# MVCC and next-key different

Tags: mysql, innodb

These two can solve the phantom reading of MySql under the isolation level of repeatable read. What scenarios will use MVCC and what scenarios will use next-key?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand the question! What kind of scenarios are you talking about?

Comment: MVCC is used to prevent dirty read between multiple cocurrent transaction.While next-key lock is used to solve phantom reading problem

Comment: MVCC is used for non-locking reads and next-key locking is used for everything else (locking reads and locking writes).